# How to turn a SVG image to a SDL surface or an array of RGBA pixels with python?

Tags: python, svg, sdl, rgb

I'm guessing it has to be done with the aid of some sort of framework. Google gives libCairo as the most common result, but that is way too many dependencies.

I mean something that would work on Win/Lin/OSX, be non-GPL, python-compatible, freely re-distributable. And preferably a few hundred KB in size.

Thing is, it doesn't even have to support the full SVG spec. Just lines, shapes, gradient fills and blur.

Alternatively, is there any vector format that could be more easily used?

Answer (score 1):

Try python-rsvg from http://www.cairographics.org/pyrsvg/

Too many dependencies? Really? http://www.cairographics.org/download/ has Windows binaries. It depends on `libpng` and `zlib`. Don't know about getting the Python bindings up though. If the bindings are too hard, you could just shell out to `rsvg file.svg output.png`.

You might try searching PyPi for 'svg': http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=svg&submit=search . There is a SVG loader for OpenGL in there somewhere.